# Multiplication as repeated addition?

Tags: scheme, multiplication, addition

I am new to Scheme. I am attempting to write a program that defines (integer) multiplication as repeated addition. In python the program would look something like:

```
a = int(raw_input(['please enter a number to be multiplied']))
b = int(raw_input(['please enter a number to multiply by']))

y = a
print y
for i in range(b-1):
    y+=a
print y
```

There are two problems I have when attempting to write in Scheme, one 'hard' and one 'soft':

1. The 'hard' problem: I cannot find an equivalent of the range function in Scheme. How should I implement this?
2. The 'soft' problem: At this point in the book, for loops have not been introduced for Scheme, which leads me to believe the solution does not contain a for loop; however, I am fine with using a for loop if that is easier/better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use recursion in place of iteration.  The general idea is:

```
mult(a, b)
    if b == 0, return 0
    return a + mult(a, b-1)
```

Now, can you code that in Scheme on your own?

Answer (score 0):

In Racket (a Scheme derivative) there is "named let" where one can keep adding in each loop for b times (easier to understand this concept):

```
(let loop ((n 0)
           (s 0))
  (cond
    ([= n b]  s)
    (else (loop (add1 n) (+ s a)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

DrRacket Scheme code should be like that:

```
    (define mult
      (lambda (a b)
      (if (= b 0)
          b
          (+ a (mult a (- b 1))))))
     
    (mult 4 5)
```